# (Roblox) Multiple clones of tool are being sent to a player's backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game where I would like to send a tool that I have in ServerStorage to all players on a specific team when a remoteevent is triggered, and so far the script is working but there is one problem when testing, the tool for some reason is duplicated twice and sent to the players backpack, I also had a friend try it with me in game and it made 4 duplicates and sent it to both of our backpacks.
Here is the script:

```
local trigger = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("CDRiotTrigger")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local item1 = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("ClassicSword")

trigger.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace:WaitForChild("riotst").Playing = true
    game.Workspace:WaitForChild("riotst"):Play()
    for _, player in pairs(teams["Class - D"]:GetPlayers()) do
        local clone1 = item1:Clone()
        clone1.Parent = player.Backpack
        print(player.name.." received")
    end
end)
```

I expected 1 clone of the tool to be sent to each players backpack, but instead it sends multiple

Comment: What code is triggering the CDRiotTrigger:FireServer() event?

Comment: @Kylaaa a localscript that is elsewhere in the game

Comment: Seeing that might give insight as to when this code executes

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:

```
local trigger = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("CDRiotTrigger")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local item1 = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("ClassicSword")

trigger.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace:WaitForChild("riotst").Playing = true
    game.Workspace:WaitForChild("riotst"):Play()
    for _, player in pairs(teams["Class - D"]:GetPlayers()) do
        if not player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("ClassicSword")
            local clone1 = item1:Clone()
            clone1.Parent = player.Backpack
            print(player.name.." received")
        end
    end
end)
```